# PHP: array_unshift after array_unique returns integer

Tags: php, arrays

I recently tried to create an array with multiple Strings, representing the AcceptLanguage header. I need to push another user-specified language to the start of the array, to make it max priority.

So far I have

```
function getRequestLangs(){
    //get languages from browser
    $accLangs = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

    $requestedLanguages = array();
    foreach($accLangs as $key => $lang){

        $lang = substr($lang,0,2);
        // p is a quality param, we won't need it, since the
        // preferred languages are already sorted by default 
        if($lang != 'p='){
            array_push($requestedLanguages,$lang);
        }
    }
    // we only need each language once, this function keeps the order
    return array_unique($requestedLanguages);
}
```

Now I want to add the user-specified language as first key (in case the language is not supportet, I may fall back to another accepted language)

```
//language from path, pushed as first index (highest priority)
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ""){
        $requestedLanguages = array_unshift($requestedLanguages,$_GET['lang']);
}
```

`var_dump($requestedLanguages)` before array_unshift:

```
    array(2) { 
         [0]=> string(2) "de" 
         [2]=> string(2) "en" 
    }
```

`var_dump($requestedLanguages)` after array_unshift:

```
    int(3)
```

I think it might have to do with the index-hole between 0 and 2, but that is only a guess.

[EDIT]
i need more caffeine...

```
//wrong:
$requestedLanguages = array_unshift($requestedLanguages,$_GET['lang']);

//right:
array_unshift($requestedLanguages,$_GET['lang']);
```

Comment: [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/function.array-unshift.php)... *Returns the new number of elements in the array.*

Comment: yes. i saw that like 30 seconds after i postet this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_unshift` mutates the supplied array and returns the new number of elements in the array after the item was prepended to it, so the `int(3)` is telling you that there are now three items in the array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: Maybe you should accept this answer if it answers your question :-)

Comment: yea, i wanted to do that, but it gave me "you may accept it in 3 minutes"